# Collect values between two words - sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring, charindex

I've been working on collecting values between two specific words.

I have one working fine but the other seems to throw an error which I just can't work out...

Field value (NVARCHAR):

```
** Service Details **  Service Line: 0000000010  Service No: 000000000003001441  Service Text: SMPR Small meter problem  Service Qty: 55.06    ** Appointment Details **  17.07.2018 11:55 To 16.08.2018 11:55
```

Script I am using:

```
REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING([description_long],CHARINDEX('Service No:',[description_long])-1,CHARINDEX('Service Text:',[description_long])-CHARINDEX('Service No:',[description_long])+0), 14, 100),char(13),'') AS [serviceNo] 
REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING([description_long],CHARINDEX('Service Text:',[description_long])-1,CHARINDEX('Service Qty:',[description_long])-CHARINDEX('Service Text:',[description_long])+0), 16, 2000),char(13),'') AS [serviceText]
```

So the Service line gives me: `0000000010` as expected but the service text gives me:

> Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

I've tried changing the "-" to a "+"

```
REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING([description_long],CHARINDEX('Service Text:',[description_long])-1,CHARINDEX('Service Qty:',[description_long])+CHARINDEX('Service Text:',[description_long])+0), 16, 2000),char(13),'') AS [serviceText]
```

Which gives me no error and the value:

```
 SMPR Small meter problem  Service Qty: 55.06    ** Appointment Details**  17.07.2018 11:55 To 16.08.2018 11:55
```

Where am I going wrong here? - Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (Description_long nvarchar(1000));

INSERT INTO @T VALUES (N'** Service Details **  Service Line: 0000000010  Service No: 000000000003001441  Service Text: SMPR Small meter problem  Service Qty: 55.06    ** Appointment Details **  17.07.2018 11:55 To 16.08.2018 11:55  ');

SELECT 
 RTRIM(
  REPLACE(
   SUBSTRING(
    [description_long],
    CHARINDEX('Service No:', [description_long]),
    CHARINDEX('Service Text:',[description_long]) - CHARINDEX('Service No:', [description_long])
  ), 
  'Service No: ', '')) AS [serviceNo],

 RTRIM(
  REPLACE(
   SUBSTRING(
    [description_long],
    CHARINDEX('Service Text:', [description_long]),
    CHARINDEX('Service Qty:',[description_long]) - CHARINDEX('Service Text:', [description_long])
   ),
  'Service Text: ', '')) AS [serviceText]

FROM @T
```